# Copy child Job schema inactive

Tags: schema, jobs, talend

I'm trying to retrieve a child job dataflow output in a parent job in talend. I've read everywhere that in order to do that, you should click on "Copy Child Job Schema" in the component view of tRunJob, but that button is disabled for me. Does anyone know what should I do in order to be able to click on "Copy Child Job Schema" and retrieve the output of the child job?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post a few relevant screenshots of your job please?

Comment: Here are the screenshots: Parent job:
![Parent Job](http://i59.tinypic.com/30ixdle.png).
Child job:
![Child Job](http://i60.tinypic.com/axh9qh.jpg).

Comment: Your tRunJob doesn't have a job selected. Try dragging the job from the repository directly on to the canvas.

Comment: done that too (it was the way i tried it in the first place), but the result is still the same ... it really seems as a limitation of TOS

Comment: [This TOS tutorial](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide54EN/tRunJob) seems to imply otherwise.

Comment: Yes, and it's not the only one... All the articles I found on this subject imply the usage of that button, but it just doesn't work for me... That is why I asked the question in the first place: I'd like to understand in which condition this button is active and in which it's inactive...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of a properly configured tRunJob and inactive "..." and "Copy child job schema" buttons?

Comment: Here's the screenshot : ![Parent Job](http://i62.tinypic.com/307t4sh.png). Please note that "..." is not inactive, only "Copy child job schema". I'm able to manually define the schema, it's the Copy child job schema that doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this option is not available on the TOS (free version). Seems to be the same case as for the joblets...

Comment: Joblets aren't available in TOS but you should be able to take data from the buffer in a child job easily enough.